# How to have a custom cookie name in spring security

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, spring-security, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have two applications `A` and `B` which are running on the same server, with different ports. As cookies are not port-specific, these two applications are using the same cookie `JSESSIONID`. When I log in to one of them, I get kicked out from the other.

So I need to modify the cookie name for each of these applications. How can I have a custom cookie name? *If it helps, I am using spring security.*

---

**Problem Solved**
As Michael pointed out, I did not need to change the `JSESSIONID` name at all. Both applications use the same `URL/Path` and that's why the second cookie replaces the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You should not change the name of the JSESSIONID cookie. The cookies are not port specific but they are application path specific. The default behavior is to set the JSESSIONID cookie according to the application path and the cookie from one application should not interfere with the cookie of the second application. I take spring-security-samples-contacts-3.1.0.RELEASE.war and copy it twice to the webapp folder of the same server: test.war and contacts.war.
I have opened both application in the same browser. 
I use Fiddler and I see the following:
When I login to the contacts application Tomcat set cookie to path `contacts`:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=408F79D16A8665C73F5C30D66B102DA6; Path=/contacts/; HttpOnly
```

Similar with the test application:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ECAE9734E9A277F1E96D678BB67E558B; Path=/test/; HttpOnly
```

Then, I can work on both applications in the same time without a problem

Comment: In fact the value of `JSESSIONID`s are different. But as soon as I log in one of these applications, I get thrown away from the other. I have two further questions though, **1)** what could my problem be? **2)** What is fiddler and where can I find it?

Comment: Fiddler is a free proxy, that allows to intercept HTTP requests and response: http://fiddler2.com/.
It can help to understand what is your problem.
Also, may be it will be useful to add your Spring Security configuration files to the question.

Comment: Although this is not the answer of the question, you went all this way to show me a point. So as a _Thank you_ I up-vote your answer.